# Android Notification doesn't show on version 4.2.2

Tags: android, push-notification

Here is how I show a notification:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MalwareListActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_white)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!")
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .build();

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
```

It works find on Android 5.1 but doesn't on v4.2.2.

On v4.2.2 device (I use OPPO R831K), the notification show and hide immediately.

Do I make anything wrong?

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with your code.

Comment: So, the problem is come from OPPO device? But other apps display notifications fine, such as Gmail

Comment: "the problem is come from OPPO device?" -- or possibly from other code that you have not shown here (e.g., you are accidentally cancelling the notification).

Comment: No, I already delete canceling code but still same issue. The notification show and then hide automatically, right after 0.1 seconds I think. On other devices, it work like a charm.

Comment: Then try it on another 4.2 environment, such as the emulator. My guess is that you will find that it works there. As to why your specific notification does not work on the OPPO, while others do, I cannot say.

Comment: Nice idea, I will try on some 4.2 emulator to see how it works